# Is it possible to flash a boot.img kernel with TWRP?

Tags: twrp, kernel

I'm looking to flash a ROM's `boot.img` on another ROM with TWRP 3.0. Is it possible?

If it's relevant, both ROMs are CM-based running Android 5.1 Lollipop.

Comment: still works by 2021+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boot into TWRP, select Install and follow the screenshots for the rest.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

It's not a problem for TWRP to which ROM your particular kernel belongs. The size should not be greater than the partition. That's all.

If the kernel is not good for the ROM, your device would not boot into the ROM or would cause some other instability, so proceed with caution.

Comment: To install kernel, what partition to select from boot, recovery, or splash?

Comment: @Rahul Boot partition.

Comment: @Firelord how do you make twrp look like that?

Comment: @answerSeeker I did not customize this TWRP (it is unofficial version for Nexus 6 compatible with MultiROM). But, you can look into Material themes and splash screens available for TWRP. There are lots of tutorials on YouTube.