# How to install TWRP if usb device not recognised?

Tags: fastboot, windows, twrp

I am able to list my Redmi Note from cmd via `fastboot devices` on Windows 10.

But I want to flash the latest TWRP on my old HTC One XL. I am able to get it recognised by `adb devices`. Then I can to to fastboot via `adb reboot bootloader`. But then fastboot devices returns nothing.

Windows complains that `USB device was not recognised`

I do have the latest `platform-tools`

[image]

I did install the latest HTC Sync Manager. HTC One XL is not listed there as supported though.

**Q1)** Any idea how to make fastboot work?

**Q2)** or even better how to flash the latest TWRP to HTC One XL? I got TWRP 2.8.4.0 already there

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have the proper drivers yet - I remembered it isn't called "Sync Manager".

Comment: In bootloader, is the device showing Fastboot USB ?

Comment: Why are you going through all this trouble? Through your installed TWRP you can simply flash your new TWRP image.  Example: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/139674/96277

Comment: @esQmo, yes I can see fastboot usb. I have to scroll down with volume button to have `fastboot` changed to `fastboot usb` though

Comment: So the drivers are installed and you can fastboot. Windows is showing this error probably your USB cable bor connector is damaged

Comment: I didn't try to flash the image. I just tried to run `fastboot devices` and it returned nothing. The same cable, the same usb port with different mobile of mine worked.

Comment: @Firelord it worked nicely. Do you want to create a question out of your comment? So I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a version of TWRP flashed and working, you can use it to flash your new recovery image without the aid of a PC.

Boot into TWRP, select Install and follow the screenshots for the rest.

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

If you know where the recovery partition corresponds to under `/dev`, you can also use TWRP's command-line feature.

Comment: TWRP 2.x doesn't have image installation capabilities, from what I remember.

Comment: @Andy, please follow this comment of OP: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164333/how-to-install-twrp-if-usb-device-not-recognised/164416?noredirect=1#comment210425_164333

Comment: Just throwing in some personal experience, maybe I remembered wrong about the exact version number (maybe 2.7?), but image capabilities _is_ added somewhat recently. Whatever works, have an upvote.